# animateWithDuration not execute^ while tableView scrolliing

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I call the method:

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
                      delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay 
                    options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options 
                 animations:(void (^)(void))animations 
                 completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

from the UIScrollView delegate method:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
                     withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity 
              targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
```

So in iOS 7 all fine, and my method executes, in iOS 6 it begins being executed but it shows animations only after the tableView stops scrolling. So how can I execute this animation in iOS 6 during scrolling of the tableView ?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work (which is why this is a comment), but did you use the `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` option?

Comment: Did you try putting the animation code in - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView delegate method?